# how to start/stop smtp or make error on smtp from different (dev or test) machine

Tags: c#, smtp

I have a window service (C#) which is using to sent email and I have below smtp configuration,

```
<SMTP>
    <add key="SMTPport" value="25"></add>
    <add key="SMTPserver" value="smtp.XYZ.com"></add>
</SMTP>
```

When smtp is wrong, I am trying to write some log.

Currently I m doing the testing by putting wrong smtp name and manually start/stop the window service.

Is there any way that I have not to change the config file for changing the smtp name and service manual start/stop is not required?

I would like to find a way, where service is running and behind I can make some error or start/stop smtp? Please suggest!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way that I have **not to change the config file** for changing the **smtp name** and service manual start/stop is not required?

Certainly, just replace configuration via config files with code-based configuration.

e.g.

```
var client = new SmtpClient("someserver.com", 25);
```

Comment: no, I don't want to change the config or code for smtp. Just looking for a solution where I can do some change to smtp without changing application config or code

Comment: I am trying to connect smtp server which is host is different machine, not in local machine

Comment: @shaziaperween no idea what you mean.  And no idea where local machine reference came from